# PHP and Apache Segmentation Fault with large variable size

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

I seem to be having a really weird problem. I have a single variable (string) where I am storing some data. As soon as the data stored in that variable exceeds 2KB, Apache Seg faults and PHP returns an error 324.

I am saving this in my session variable (ie. $_SESSION["my_index"]) and can't change that due to the nature of the script.

Environment:

CentOS 5 64bit.
PHP 5.2.16 (Can't upgrade since 5.3 is not supported by ZendOptimizer). 
Zend Version 2.2.0.
Apache 2.2.3`

The only thing httpd logs mention is:
[Thu Apr 14 01:57:00 2011] [notice] child pid 22493 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Thanks

EDIT: It seems like $_SESSION is not the culprit. I have tried using another variable name that is not predefined by PHP and the same error occurs

Comment: please suply information about your environment such as operating system, php version, apache version, as well as your log files.

Comment: 1. We've solved this issue by downgrading system's kernel (unfortunately, can't provide exact version). 2. We solved this issue by moving to nginx + php-frm.

Comment: Are you performing some regex function on the string? Once got a silent segmentation fault by using `preg_replace` with a mal-formed regex on a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a test case so you can crash PHP when running in CLI mode. You can then compile PHP and run the script in GDB to create a backtrace.